# Getting text inside a tag, after another tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, tags

I´m scraping some webs with selenium and bs4 and I´m in need of some elegant code to do the following. I have some text inside a tag.

```
<td><a href="javascript:Team(14654)"><span class="hp">1</span>SJK Seinajoen</a></td
```

If I do this

```
find('td').get_text()
```

What I get is

```
1SJK Seinajoen
```

as it gets all text, including what is in span tag. My question is, is there any way to get the text inside a tags that is after span tag in a pythonic way?

I say pythonic because I could always do split with the resulting string, but that is not very elegant

Comment: What's the page you're scraping?

Comment: What results are you expecting from the elements you have pasted above? Is it `1 SJK Seinajoen` or just `SJK Seinajoen`? If the second one you need then I suppose you have got your question answered already.

Comment: I expect to get the name of the team without the '1' that is inside span tags

Answer (score 0):

This is from another post about this issue:

If you are using bs4 you can use `strings`:

```
" ".join(result.strings)
```

Answer (score 0):

In [lxml.html](http://lxml.de/installation.html) you can use below code to get required output:

```
from lxml import html

source = """<td><a href="javascript:Team(14654)"><span class="hp">1</span>SJK Seinajoen</a></td>"""
html = html.fromstring(source)  # pass web page HTML source code as "source" var
print(html.xpath("//a/text()")[0])
```

*Output*

```
"SJK Seinajoen"
```